# Change Marionette ItemView template dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, marionette

I have this `ItemView` in `Marionette`:

```
App.View.MovieListItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
tagName: 'li',
className: 'movie',
model: App.Model.Movie,
id: function() {
    return 'movie-'+this.model.get('imdb')
},

initialize: function () {
    this.render();
},

template: _.template('<a href="javascript:;">'+
        '<i class="fa fa-eye fa-3"></i>'+
        '<span class="cover"></span>'+
        '<strong><%= title %></strong>'+
        '<small><%- year %></small>'+
        '<small2>Cached</small2>'+
    '</a>'),
});
```

And i want to know if it's possible to create the template dynamically?
Because some time i want(Base on method that check something) to remove the `small2` tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Marionette has a function](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#change-which-template-is-rendered-for-a-view) called `getTemplate` which can be used to return dynamic templates.

Example:

```
App.View.MovieListItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'movie',
    model: App.Model.Movie,
    id: function() {
        return 'movie-'+this.model.get('imdb')
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },

    getTemplate: function(){
        if(condition){
            return _.template(/* HTML STRING */);
        }else{
            return _.template(/* ANOTHER HTML STRING */);
        }
    }
});
```